# With "span-joining-supported" brave tracer feature, dont get to propagate spanIds to other service using feign

Tags: java, spring-boot, micrometer-tracing

With sprint boot 3.1.5 in two microservices, one using FeignClient to request to the other microservice , I have this properties configuration in both microservices:

```
management:
  tracing:
    propagation:      
      produce: b3
      consume: b3
    brave:
      span-joining-supported: true

logging:
  pattern:
    level: "%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-},%X{parentId:-}]"
```

I have next library in both poms:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.6</version>
 </dependency>
```

I have this FeignConfiguration lets called in microservice A to get the context propagated to the microservice B:

```
@Configuration
public class FeignConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public Capability capability(final MeterRegistry registry) {
      return new MicrometerCapability(registry);
    }    
}
```

I have this in order to log PARENT_ID in both microservices and is working fine:

```
@Configuration
public class BraveTracerConfig {
    
    @Bean
    CorrelationScopeCustomizer parentIdCorrelationScopeCustomizer() {
        return builder -> builder.add(SingleCorrelationField.create(BaggageFields.PARENT_ID));
    }

}
```

When microservice A calls microservice B, traceId is propagated but I dont see in microservice B in the logs the spanId or parentId logged in the feignClient from the microservice A, they are different except for traceId. According to the brave configuration I used, it is supposed I can get it according to this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/35165, right?

Thanks!